# ndk-bulid problem with bulit file Macintosh (CR) and Unix (LF)

Tags: android-ndk, ndk-build

I'm trying to build my native library (C++) but I always end up with output file as Macintosh (CR) and not Unix (LF)

here's my files:

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := test1
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocode.cpp
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -std=gnu++0x -Wall -fPIE         
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog -fPIE -pie  

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Application.mk

```
APP_STL := c++_static
APP_ABI := arm64-v8a armeabi-v7a x86 x86_64
APP_PLATFORM := android-21
APP_OPTIM := release
APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++14 -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -DNDEBUG -Wall -fpermissive -fpic
APP_LDFLAGS := -llog
APP_THIN_ARCHIVE := true
APP_PIE         := true
```

Bulid.bat:

```
"C:\Users\UserOne\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.0.6113669\ndk-build"
```

[Output file must be Unix(LF) otherwise it won't work, How I can fix it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVHxj.png)

Comment: I don't get it. Why are you opening an executable in Notepad, and why do care what kind of line-endings Notepad thinks that this non-textfile has?

Comment: The values you point to do not appear to be parts of strings; I imagine they are not newlines in any encoding - just binary data of some sort. You say it won't work; do you get errors when you try to load this library in your app?

Comment: @Michael I asked my friend to build the file, and I compare my file with his, the only differences I found is this.
@-zenzelezz No error, if there is an error I would post it for sure!

Comment: Ok, but it makes no sense to talk about line endings for an executable. DId you try to run it on an Android device and see if it works? Or if you really want to know what the difference between the two builds of the executable are, then at least use a tool that's appropriate for the task (e.g. `readelf`).